# Angular Slick changing current-index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slick.js

I have a row of slick items, and after loading them, I would like to go to a pre-selected section of items. There are 6 items per page and I would like to go to item 8, let's say.

I change the current-index attribute to 8.

This unfortunately works for a second...then it goes back to zero (I have it printed out). This also appears to break my next/prev arrow functionality, it always resets to zero.

I would have liked to use slickGoTo, but that method is not made available via angular-slick

Comment: Some code and accompanied by a plunkr or fiddle would help a lot. I doubt anyone can solve this by just reading this.